# Get locale date in same display format as UTC date in server side Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a date such as

```
let date = new Date('2019-05-15T13:06:41Z')
```

that I wish to get in exactly the same format but in a provided locale. This is on a server so I'm also passing a locale in (which I do have access to)

so imagine the server is based in the US, but I have an en-GB locale. I want to get the date and time in exactly the same format e.g yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss but in whatever locale I pass in.

So in the above instance it should return (accounting for BST)

```
2019-05-15T14:06:41
```

I know on the client I can do:

```
let date = new Date('2019-05-15T13:06:41Z')
let formatted_date = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "T" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
```

but as I say on the server this won't work as it's based on the server time and not the locale I need.

happy to use momentjs or something similar if this is easy to achieve

Comment: I did fully not understood your question, please note that [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) != [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/locale/info). Probably you can take a look at [moemnt-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Note: locales don't and can't map 1:1 to timezones.

```
let date = new Date('2019-05-15T13:06:41Z');
moment(date).tz('Asia/Tokyo').toISOString(true);       // 2019-05-15T22:06:41.000+09:00
moment(date).tz('Asia/Kolkata').toISOString(true);     // 2019-05-15T18:36:41.000+05:30
moment(date).tz('America/New_York').toISOString(true); // 2019-05-15T09:06:41.000-04:00"
```

Comment: I've ended up using moment-timezone for this. The issue I had was it was a 3rd party API and it didn't give me the timezone with the initial request. However I've since discovered they have an additional API I can call that does provide this info, so problem solved with an extra API call and moment-timezone